# If I turn on JavaScript, can my workplace see what sites I'm using TOR to access?

Tags: anonymity, javascript, java, tor-network

My question is about what my ISP can see if I enable JavaScript on a site.I would like to use TOR to access sites without letting my work know, but some sites will only work with JavaScript on.
If I turn on JavaScript, can my workplace see what sites I'm using TOR to access?
I am not doing anything illegal so I'm not worried about total anonymity from a government or anything like that. I just want to browse on work wifi without work knowing what sites I'm on.
I do FetLife and Onlyfans photography. I would like to check in with potential clients/models while at work, but I don't want to be unprofessional by having those sites on the work wifi. Also, data without wifi is a no-go as the building blocks the signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you'll use an isolated VM for that - nobody will know for sure. If you'll use just Tor browser - it's mostly safe according to your situation, but leaks are possible